# Why is my variable variable not referencing the json data?

Tags: php, json, dynamic-variables

I have tried to understand and solve this issue to no end. I think I'm close in that I suspect I'm simply referencing my json data incorrectly, but I cannot figure out how to do it right. Here's the use case.

I'm building a simple ledger system to track crypto transactions. The system also does some nice tallying of coin totals, calculates coin values in USD, and caculates overall portfolio value etc.

I let the user track coins of their choice that sit in an array called $coins. The $coins array is initialized earlier in my code via a database call and contains $coin->ID and the $coin->symbol.

To determine coin values in USD, I make a call out to CryptoCompare using their API, which, after grabbing the coin symbols from my $coins array, looks something like this:

```
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ADA,BTC,ETH,LTC&tsyms=USD
```

Just pop that URL into a browser to [view the results](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ADA,BTC,ETH,LTC&tsyms=USD) set.

$price_request_data stores that data after being decoded.

Now my problem arises when I try to reference the JSON data via my $coins loop. I can reference the data just fine if I use a direct reference such as:

```
$price_request_data->BTC->USD
```

That produces a value of 15592.

But obviously I want to loop through my $coins loop and dynamically create variables for each coin to hold its respective price. When I try to reference the JSON data in this way, it fails to retrieve the price ( 15592) and instead returns 0.

```
        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        // GET CURRENT PRICES

        $apiurl = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ADA,BTC,ETH,LTC&tsyms=USD";

        $price_request = wp_remote_get( $apiurl );

        if( is_wp_error( $price_request ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $price_request_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $price_request );

        $price_request_data = json_decode( $price_request_body );

        if( ! empty( $price_request_data ) ) {

            echo $price_request_data->BTC->USD . "<br />"; // PRODUCES 15592

            foreach( $coins as $coin ) {

                $pricereqdata = "price_request_data->" . $coin->symbol . "->USD";

                echo $$pricereqdata; // PRODUCES 0

                // Generate the variable name string i.e. "curpricebtc"
                $curprice = "curprice" . strtolower( $coin->symbol );

                // Format the current coin's price
                $$curprice = number_format( ceil_dec( $$pricereqdata, 2 ), 2, ".", "" );


            }

        }
```

This is the vardump of $price_request_data:

```
object(stdClass)#1527 (4) {
  ["ADA"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1528 (1) {
    ["USD"]=>
    float(0.4469)
  }
  ["BTC"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1535 (1) {
    ["USD"]=>
    float(15592)
  }
  ["ETH"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1536 (1) {
    ["USD"]=>
    float(757.13)
  }
  ["LTC"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1539 (1) {
    ["USD"]=>
    float(291.21)
  }
}
```

I'm using PHP7 and I know some reference rules changed, but I was not able to determine if that's my issue. I swear it's just the way I'm referencing it with a variable variable, but I'm not experienced enough to know why.

Any wisdom is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't use strings as chains.

Comment: Ok I think I know what you mean... you're saying that you can't generate a chain ( $price_request_data->BTC->USD ) in the way I did "price_request_data->" . $coin->symbol . "->USD". In other words you can't assemble a chain using strings. That begs the question then, how do you reference the JSON prices without hard-coding 1500 "chains"?

Comment: `$pricereqdata = $price_request_data->{$coin->symbol}->USD; echo $pricereqdata;` should work.

Comment: Holiday delays but I will give this a try and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

OK:

Q: Does "$price_request_data" equal `{"ADA":{"USD":0.4738},"BTC":{"USD":15486.46},"ETH":{"USD":786.47},"LTC":{"USD":306.48}}` (or equivalent)?

<= Your comment, "// WORKS", implies "yes"

Q: Where is "$coin" initializated?  What is its value?

Q: What is a value of "$pricereqdata"?

Q: Does "$$pricereqdata" create a new variable for you?  What is it?  What is its value?

In other words, exactly what do you mean by "// FAILS"???

Comment: Okay I edited my code to make thing clearer and I think I answered all your questions by doing so. $pricereqdata contains the string "price_request_data->BTC->USD" where BTC varies as you loop through $coins. $$pricereqdata should produce a value of 15592 but doesn't. It return 0.

Comment: Look at Jon Stirling's response above: `$pricereqdata = $price_request_data->{$coin->symbol}->USD; echo $pricereqdata;`  Please let us know how you resolved the problem.